# $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] - How to configure

Tags: php, apache

According to PHP.net, in order to use the $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] variable, *'Your web server must be configured to create this variable. For example in Apache you'll need HostnameLookups On inside httpd.conf for it to exist.'*

I am stumped as to how to configure this. Firstly, how do I know if my web server is Apache or not? My website's host is freeola.net, but I have no idea whether its web server is Apache or not.

If it isn't, how can I configure the server to allow this variable?

If it is, how do I get access to the httpd.conf file? Is it accessed within the FTP client (I use Filezilla, if that's relevant)?

I would really appreciate some guidance, thanks!

Comment: don't. it forces apache to do a reverse DNS lookup for EVERY hit it receives, and performance will tank. If you want the hostname, then get a log analyzer or whatever and do the reversee lookup at the time you actually need to do it.

Comment: Ok... I'm still a relative beginner in PHP so correct me if I've got the wrong end of the stick. So what superglobal or network function should I use? Something like gethostbyaddr()?

Comment: what are you trying to do? remote_host is (if configured) the name of the CLIENT connecting to the webserver, and has nothing to do with the webserver's own name(s).

Comment: What I want to collect is the name of the machine accessing the webpage, e.g if a client accessed the webpage something along the lines of 'Joe's Laptop' would be recorded.

Comment: you're already recording the IP address in the server's access log. there's no need to lookup the hostname "live". it'll just slow your server down.

Comment: I will be recording the IP address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Comment: But I need to uniquely identify the client, which might not be achieved if there lots of clients all accessing the same website under, for example, a corporate IP address.

Comment: you can't detect the hostname of a computer behind a proxy/NAT gateway. you simply CAN'T. all you'll get is the ip/hostname of the proxy/gateway

Comment: Ah okay, I'll see what I can think of. Thanks for setting it straight :)